# "einerseits" vs. "auf der einen Seite" vs. "zum einen" vs. "zum Ersten" vs. "erstens"

Tags: adverb, conjunction, linking-elements

Could you please tell me if these constructions can be used interchangeably, like in the following example:

1. Einerseits habe ich keine Zeit, andererseits kannst du das auch alleine machen.
2. Auf der einen Seite habe ich keine Zeit, auf der anderen Seite kannst du das auch alleine machen.
3. Zum einen habe ich keine Zeit, zum anderen kannst du das auch alleine machen.
4. Zum Ersten habe ich keine Zeit, zum Zweiten kannst du das auch alleine machen.
5. Erstens habe ich keine Zeit, zweitens kannst du das auch alleine machen.

Also, can I put a full stop, instead of a comma, between the two sentences/clauses?

Answer (score 1):

"Einerseits" and "auf der einen Seite" can probably be used interchangeably as einerseits is just a short version of "auf der einen Seite". Though the combination einerseits/andererseits implies that you're weighing options and are having a pro/con analysis like "on the one hand I should exercise and go for a walk, but on the other hand it's really cold outside". Like on the one hand your listing arguments in favor of something and one the other hand you're listing arguments against something.

So outside of jokes, where you play with that expectation of pro and con and instead hit them with something bad and something even worse, this is probably less common.

So if you're just going to list reasons for why you don't want to do something the third option is probably best. That is if there are only 2, if there are more then enumerating them with 5. option makes it probably sound even more daunting (like "Oh shit, he's already at "viertens" and still going strong"). Outside of sentences like "zum Ersten Mal" (for the first time) I'd not be aware of the "zum Ersten" option and would recommend the "Erstens" instead.

So TL/DR "einerseits/anderseits" = "Auf der einen Seite/Auf der anderen Seite", "Zum einen/zum anderen" interchangeable to "Ersten/Zeitens" but the latter lets you count on if you need to.

Comment: Many thanks to you & @bakunin for your feedback. I think I'm mainly having a hard time with //zum einen...zum anderen//, as it can be used both to list different, usually opposite, points of view, like this sentence: //Sport kann zum einen sehr anstrengend sein, zum anderen aber auch viel Spaß machen.// And also for enumeration, like this sentence: //Das Produkt ist zum einen sehr teuer und zum anderen nicht einmal besonders gut.//

Answer (score 1):

@haxor789 has already addressed most of the points, here are just a few points for the sake of completeness:

> Outside of sentences like "zum Ersten Mal" (for
> the first time) I'd not be aware of the "zum
> Ersten" option

It might be a regional phenomenon, but where i come from this is quite common too and used interchangeably with "erstens, zweitens, drittens, ...."

> Also, can I put a full stop, instead of a comma,
> between the two sentences/clauses?

It won't be a serious error and will definitely be understood without any raised eyebrows if you do, but in a very strict sense you can't. "Einerseits - andererseits" is used as a phrase (quite like "either - or" in english) and it goes against my sense of language to separate these in different sentences.

The arguably most correct form is to use commas to separate simple list elements:

> Dazu habe ich erstens (zum ersten) keine Zeit, zweitens (zum zweiten) kannst du das selber amchen und drittens (zum dritten) fällt mir sicher noch was ein.

If the list elements are so complex they contain commas themselves use semicolons to separate them:

> Dazu habe ich erstens, wie ich schon ausführte, keine, nicht einmal die geringste, Zeit; zweitens, auch das haben wir schon besprochen, kannst du das, ein wenig guten Willen vorausgesetzt, auch selber machen; drittens, wenn ich nur lange genug nachdenke, fallen mir sicher noch ein paar Gründe ein, [...]

Also notice that there are other devices to create a "list-like" enumeration without counting: "außerdem", "darüber hinaus", "dazu kommt, ..." "nicht zu vergessen". i.e.

> Da habe ich nicht die geringste Zeit und außerdem auch nicht dem Willen, darüber hinaus kannst du das selber machen, sowie, nicht zu vergessen, weitere Gründe bestehen, [weshalb ich deiner Bitte nicht entsprechen werde].